# How to retrieve image from Firebase Storage using Python?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-storage

I have already store my image to Firebase Storage, and I need to take it out by using Python code. Can I retrieve the image by using any URL? Or is there any way to retrieve it out?

Here are the image of how I store it in Firebase Storage:

[image: Here are the image of how I store it in Firebase Storage]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what I use. Hope it helps.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import storage

# Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
cred = credentials.Certificate("credentials.json")

# Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'storageBucket': '<BUCKET_NAME>.appspot.com',
}, name='storage')

bucket = storage.bucket(app=app)
blob = bucket.blob("<your_blob_path>")

print(blob.generate_signed_url(datetime.timedelta(seconds=300), method='GET'))
```

It generates a **public URL** (for 300 secs) for you to download your files.

For example, in my case, I use that URL to display stored pictures in my django website with `<img>` tag.

[Here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob) is the doc for more usefull functions.

Comment: I don't understand that "Fetch the service account key JSON file contents" part, what is that use for, and how to do it?

Comment: In your Firebase console, go to Project Overview (left panel) > Project Configuration. Then go to service accounts and press "Generate new private key". Check [this](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiz472kmdfeAhVGD5AKHZ_LD98QjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example-code.com%2Fpython%2Ffirebase_access_token.asp&psig=AOvVaw3O6dTLIn2vyCY3C_CyJNhC&ust=1542398761092120) picture.

Comment: Ohh it works. Thank you so much. Lol

By the way did you have any idea on downloading that image ?

Comment: Yeah, check the docs link I've added. Or just try [here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.download_to_file).

Comment: https://console.cloud.google.com/projectcreate?previousPage=%2Fprojectselector%2Fiam-admin get the credentials from that link