# How to download images to computer from firebase

Tags: java, python

My actual plan is that a Python script should download the latest uploaded image from Firebase to a Raspberry Pi or my computer (Ubuntu).

I already tried with gsutil like this:

```
from  google.cloud import storage

import os

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="finalpro.json"

client = storage.Client(project='finalpro-5d930')

bucket = client.get_bucket('gs://finalpro-5d930.appspot.com')

blob = storage.Blob('NewUploads/', bucket)

blob.download_to_filename('/home/simon/Documents/images')
```

I need only the Python script, so that I can initialise that script in the `bashrc` file on my Raspberry Pi, so that when the Raspberry Pi boots up, it runs that script automatically to download image from Firebase.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You're likely to get more useful answers if you give a little more information about what is actually happening when you use this code? Does it work? Do you get an error? Is there some other problem?

Comment: Yeah code doesn't work, i need a better solution .

Comment: Unfortunately "doesn't work" isn't likely to get get you much help here - you need to explain exactly what the problem is, and what errors you're seeing, or how the results don't match your expectations. I'd suggest reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then coming back and editing your question with what you've learned.

Comment: I followed from this link = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53304517/how-to-retrieve-image-from-firebase-storage-using-python

Comment: I followed this link = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53304517/how-to-retrieve-image-from-firebase-storage-using-python"      I hope u understand the output i need, Just i want to download the image.  So i got the output as URL as he told in that "stack overflow" as i posted on top. But i don't know how to download image with that URL. So the problem is this: "Want to know how to download image with that URL which is generated in terminal"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Installation

```
pip install firebase
```

#### Python Version

Firebase was written for python 3 and above and will not work correctly with python 2.

#### Add Firebase to your Application

Your Google's Firebase configuration data can be found on [Firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com) > Settings > Project Settings *Scroll to bottom* > Add to web app > config

For use with only user based authentication we can create the following configuration:

```py
from firebase import Firebase

config = {
  "apiKey": "apiKey",
  "authDomain": "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
  "databaseURL": "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
  "storageBucket": "projectId.appspot.com"
}

firebase = Firebase(config)
```

Adding a service account will authenticate as an admin by default for all database queries, check out the
Authentication documentation for how to authenticate users.

### Storage

**The storage service allows you to upload images to Firebase.**

You first need to initialise your storage object:

```py
storage = firebase.storage()
```

#### child

Just like with the Database service, you can build paths to your data with the Storage service.

```py
storage.child("images/example.jpg")
```

#### put

The put method takes the path to the local file and an optional user token.

```py
storage = firebase.storage()

# as admin
storage.child("images/example.jpg").put("example2.jpg")

# as user
storage.child("images/example.jpg").put("example2.jpg", user['idToken'])
```

#### download

The download method takes the path to the saved database file and the name you want the downloaded file to have.

```
storage.child("images/example.jpg").download("downloaded.jpg")
```

#### get_url

The get_url method takes the path to the saved database file and returns the storage url.

```
storage.child("images/example.jpg").get_url()

>> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/storage-url.appspot.com/o/images%2Fexample.jpg?alt=media
```

I hope this helps. Read full docs: https://pypi.org/project/firebase

Answer (score 1):

If you need url for individual photo then :-

```
url=storage.child("images/example.jpg").get_url(example.jpg)
print(url)
```